# PhpStorm 2016 - Heroku integration?

Tags: heroku, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to connect my Node.JS + Wit.AI project built with PhpStorm 2016 to Heroku, but all the information that I find on how to do that seems to be either quite outdated or doesn't match my IDE at all...

Anyone had any success connecting Heroku to PhpStorm 2016 somehow?

So far, I tried these plugins which didn't work:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6659
- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7605

On the IntelliJ IDEA page ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-heroku.html ) it says to go in Build, Execution, Deployment | Clouds, but while I can see Build, Execution, Deployment in my settings, there is nothing close to a "Clouds" option...

Comment: Quick search showed this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15174

Comment: Damn, so it's not supported if I'm not mistaken :( Thanks

Comment: Yeah ... as I understand Cloud services available in IntelliJ IDEA only.

Comment: Can you post your input as an answer so I can select it as the answer to the question? Not sure how you found that issue, but I have had been looking for a few hours and I think it might help some people in the future too lol

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware full Clouds support available in IntelliJ IDEA only .. although some services are available in certain IDEs as well (e.g. Heroku is available in [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/heroku.html?search=heroku)).

As for PhpStorm/WebStorm -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15174 -- watch this ticket (star/comment/vote) to get notified on any progress.